# Why I need to specify an anonymous union in a namespace scope as static?

Tags: c++, unions

Why I can't define an Anonymous union in a namespace?

```
// in global namespace
union {
   int x_;
   int y_;
};
```

Or:

```
namespace Foo{
    union {
        int x_;
        int y_;
    };
}
```

- Error: 'namespace-scope anonymous aggregates must be static'
- But I solved it this way:

  ```
    namespace Foo{
        static union {
           int x_;
           int y_;
       };
   }
  ```

Or:

```
    void func(){
        union{
            int x_;
            int y_;
        }; / ok
    }
```

So can someone explain to me why I can only define an anonymous union in a namespace using the keyword `static` or I can define it as a local union?